# Google Maps API: Travel time with current traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if anyone has a way, using the google APIs (I'm not picky on version) to find out the time of a route with current traffic. I know that the total time of travel with out traffic is available, but I only need that one number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purchase a business-license, and you'll be able to get these informations(when available) by setting the `durationInTraffic` -option of the directionsRequest to `true`.

Comment: Well thank you for the answer. That is a bit of a let down google. Know of any other options that would? Bing, Mapquest, or any others?

Comment: No, I don't(which doesn't mean there don't exist any other service)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the googlemaps client API to get the driving duration in traffic using [google directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start), . For python API, refer [github page](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python)

Sample code

```
import googlemaps as gmaps
import datetime
import os

SRC = FROM_ADDRESS
DEST = TO_ADDRESS
CLIENT_KEY = os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')  # Set your directions api key as an env variable
gmaps_client = gmaps.Client(CLIENT_KEY)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
directions = gmaps_client.directions(SRC, DEST, mode="driving",departure_time=now)

# debug
# print(directions)

directions = directions[0].get('legs')[0].get('duration_in_traffic').get('text')
print(directions)
```